# Using Google App Engine as a machine learning prediction engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have no prior experience working with Google App Engine, but I'm a very experienced Java developer.

I'm interested in setting up a REST API through Google App Engine where you provide data to it, and it makes a prediction, using a predictive model that I generate separately.

The data that makes up the predictive model can be anywhere from a few hundred kilobytes, to a few megabytes when gzipped, and several times larger when decompressed.  When stored in-memory it basically consists of 10-30 HashMaps each containing anywhere from a handful to tens of thousands of entries.

During the prediction process data is retrieved from these HashMaps and combined in various ways in order to come up with the eventual prediction.  It is important that this occurs as quickly as possible to minimize latency to the API, which is why I want to keep the HashMaps in memory.

Is there a way, in Google App Engine, that I can just store this data as a serialized file, to be loaded in on startup?  I realize that I could store the data in the HashMaps in the datastore and retrieve them as-needed, but I'm worried that this will be rather slow, as a typical prediction may need to retrieve 30 different values from different HashMaps.

Even using Memcache I'm worried that this will be significantly slower than having the data stored in HashMaps within the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, App Engine instances are killed fairly regularly, so you couldn't keep HashMaps in memory between requests.

However, the recently released [Backends](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/) feature has removed this restriction.

Each Backend instance can keep up to 1GB of memory, and will remain up between requests (though they will occasionally fall over, so you should design with this in mind).

This may be worth looking into for your purposes.

Comment: You certainly could keep hashmaps in memory. There'll be some startup delay loading them, but instances can expect to serve tens to thousands of requests, depending on the app's traffic load.

Answer (score 2):

In addition the Jason's suggestion of using the new Google App Engine Backends service, another alternative is to let Google host your predictive model using the [Google Prediction API](http://code.google.com/apis/predict). It makes your model available via a REST API so you wouldn't have to build it yourself. Click on the "[Gallery](http://code.google.com/apis/predict/docs/gallery.html)" link to find out more about hosting your own models with Google. The training data is stored using the [Google Storage service](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/).

Comment: The prediction API builds the models; it doesn't let you host your own models. Still, it's probably a better idea than reinventing the service yourself.

Comment: Yes - those models were also built by the prediction service. You can't upload a pre-made model, only raw data, which the service turns into a model for you.

Comment: ah, yes, that's right. all of the ones in the gallery are. i think i was referring to the small section on the upper right that says, "Submit your own model!" or were you talking about those too? (and will you stay on vacation darn it?!?) :-)